# Jenkins MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Tags: c#, git, jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to setup a test jenkins build for a test project I'm creating. I tried to use msbuild to build the project point to sln file as I did using command line. However when I try to do that in Jenkins, I get the following error.

> 00:32:23 Fetching upstream changes from
> https://github.com/umanga89/TestProject.git 00:32:23 using GIT_ASKPASS
> to set credentials  00:32:23  > git.exe fetch --tags --force
> --progress -- https://github.com/umanga89/TestProject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10 00:32:24  > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10 00:32:24
>
> > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10 00:32:24 Checking out Revision
> > a04024299f82d9f680760713549d7c7370259f51 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> > 00:32:24  > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10 00:32:24
> > git.exe checkout -f a04024299f82d9f680760713549d7c7370259f51 # timeout=10 00:32:26 Commit message: "First commit" 00:32:26  > git.exe
> > rev-list --no-walk a04024299f82d9f680760713549d7c7370259f51 #
> > timeout=10 00:32:26 [TestProjectCSharp] $ powershell.exe
> > -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1659839037280907621.ps1 00:32:29 Path To
> > MSBuild.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> > Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe 00:32:29
> > Executing the command cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program Files
> > (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> > Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
> > TestProjectAuto.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from
> > C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TestProjectCSharp
> > 00:32:29 [TestProjectCSharp] $ cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & "C:\Program
> > Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> > Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
> > TestProjectAuto.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% 00:32:29 Active code
> > page: 1252 00:32:29 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
> > 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework 00:32:29 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 00:32:29  00:32:29 MSBUILD : error
> > MSB1009: Project file does not exist. 00:32:29 Switch:
> > TestProjectAuto.sln 00:32:29 Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project
> > or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure 00:32:32 Finished:
> > FAILURE

My jenkins build steps are as follows.

[image]

Then I try to use the downloded project from github and use msbuild.exe pathtosln in command line and I get the same error.

Any idea?